# no instance of constructor matches the argument list -- argument types are:

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting `no instance of constructor "MyClass<t>::MyClass [with t=double]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (MyClass<int>)`.

I just want to copy one object's value into another.
It work fine without template syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class t>
class MyClass{
  t x,z;
  public:
    MyClass(){}
    MyClass (const t a,const t b):x(a),z(b) {
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass& obj){
        x=(t) obj.x;
        z=(t)obj.z;
    }

    // access content:
    void  content()  {
        cout<<x<<z<<endl;

    }
};


int main () {
  MyClass<int> foo(34,23);
  MyClass <double> bar(foo);

  bar.content();
  foo.content();

  return 0;
}
```

I have searched so many questions/answers related to it but i don't find solution

Comment: In the line `MyClass<double> bar(foo)` `MyClass<int>` is not the same type as `MyClass<double>`

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to copy construct from an object of different, unrelated type. It order for `MyClass <double> bar(foo);` to work `foo` should be `MyClass <double>` as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<double>` are different types, and you only have a copy constructor that takes objects of the same type.

To get your code to work, I had to change two things:

```
template<typename u>
MyClass(const MyClass<u>& obj){
    x=(t) obj.x;
    z=(t)obj.z;
}
```

Now the constructor is templatized itself (independently of the class). This lets you construct a `MyClass<A>` from a different type `MyClass<B>`.

But just doing that leads to another error:

```
prog.cpp:14:19: error: ‘int MyClass<int>::x’ is private within this context
         x=(t) obj.x;
```

Because we're constructing from an object of an unrelated type, we don't have access to private members.

Workaround: Add a `friend` declaration in the class:

```
template<typename> friend class MyClass;
```

Comment: Thank you sir/ma'am .It help me

Comment: `code` template<class u,class m>
void fun(MyClass<u> & obj1, const MyClass<m> &obj2){
    obj1.x = (u) obj2.x;
    obj1.z = (u) obj2.z;
}`code`

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass` is a template. When you write `MyClass` inside its declaration, this is actually short-hand for `MyClass<T>`, hence `MyClass<double>` has no constructor taking a `MyClass<int>`.

If you want to allow conversions you need a second template parameter, eg

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {};

template <typename R,typename T>
foo<R> convert_foo(const foo<T>& f) { return {}; }
```

Comment: I think it works but problem will be accesing private variable

Comment: @thesummer I just wanted to show how it could be done. was planning to improve it, but the other answer already shows how to use the constructor, example was mainly to demonstrate the use of a second template parameter